# error: expected primary-expression before 'template'

Tags: c++, templates

Alright, so I'm trying to make a (for now) unbalanced binary tree. I'm getting a weird error that I can't seem to get rid of. The second half had the same error so I just got rid of it for now.

```
    void insert( binTreeNode < T >*& node, const T& obj) { // private version of insert( )
    if (obj < node->data) {
        if(node->left != NULL)
            insert(node->left, obj);
        else {
            binTreeNode<T> n;
            n = new binTreeNode(obj, NULL, NULL);
            node->left = n;
        }
    } else {
        if(node->right != NULL)
            insert(node->right, obj);
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

And the error

```
In file included from ../src/binTree.cc:2:0:
../src/binTree.h: In member function 'void binTree<T>::insert(binTreeNode<T>*&, const T&)':
../src/binTree.h:54:16: error: expected type-specifier before 'binTreeNode'
../src/binTree.h:54:16: error: expected ';' before 'binTreeNode'
src/subdir.mk:24: recipe for target `src/binTree.o' failed
make: *** [src/binTree.o] Error 1
```

binTreeNode's constructor is defined as

```
binTreeNode (const T& obj, binTreeNode < T >* leftObj = NULL, binTreeNode < T >* rightObj = NULL) {
    left = leftObj;
    right = rightObj;
    data = obj;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        n = new binTreeNode(obj, NULL, NULL);
```

Should be

```
        n = new binTreeNode<T>(obj, NULL, NULL);
```

(also, n should be a pointer).

Classes don't autodeduce template parameters from constructors even when it's unambiguous.  I'm not sure why.  Maybe it's so that the code doesn't become brittle if you add another constructor.

Anyway, if this really bugs you, you can always add a helper function:

```
template<typename T>
binTreeNode<T>* newBinTreeNode(const T& obj, binTreeNode<T>* left, binTreeNode<T>* right) {
  return new binTreeNode<T>(obj, left, right);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks again. Unfortunately, my instructor is very specific about what functions we can have in our assignments, but I try to make do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You must precede the definition of `insert()` with the `template<..>` prefix when defining a member function outside of the class declaration:

```
template <typename T>
void binTree<T>::insert(binTreeNode < T >*& node, const T& obj) {
    if (obj < node->data) {
            if(node->left != NULL)
                insert(node->left, obj);
            else {
                binTreeNode<T> n;
                n = new binTreeNode(obj, NULL, NULL);
                node->left = n;
            }
    } else {
        if(node->right != NULL)
            insert(node->right, obj);
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is the problem – from the errors, the compiler understands that this is the definition of `void binTree<T>::insert`.

Comment: @ildjarn just confused by the OP posting partial code, I guess. He doesn't even define `insert` as a member function. Must be inline...

Comment: Sorry about that. Half the code wasn't written at the time, but it was indeed inline.